# Find the average value of the average value of the image of a random finite set.

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, average

**Context:** This is part of an absurd thought experiment in which an immortal, telekinetic rat tries to push a blinking button from a variable distance while piloting a spacecraft blindfolded at relativistic speeds. I need to calculate what the rat most likely believes is the probability that the button is lit. This is my attempt to do that.

---

Fix $\omega\in\Bbb R$, and let $L:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be given by

$$L(t)=\lfloor\sin(\omega t)+1\rfloor$$

$\color{lightgray}{\text{[This is the signal controlling the light]}}$

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, let $[\Bbb R]^n=\{S\subseteq\Bbb R:|S|=n\}$. Let $[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[\Bbb R]^n$, and define $A:[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$ according to

$$\begin{align}
A(T)&=\frac1{|T|}\sum_{t\in T}\lfloor\sin(\omega t)+1\rfloor\\
&=\frac1{|T|}\sum_{t\in T}L(t)
\end{align}$$

That is, $A(T)$ is the average value of the image of $T$ under $L$.

$\color{lightgray}{\text{[Each finite subset of $\Bbb R$ corresponds to a possible set of times (as measured from the button)}\\
{\text{when information about the state of the button reaches the rat. Due to time dilation and}\\
\text{unpredictable movement (a result of the blindfold), we can assume nothing about the likelihood}\\
\text{of a given set.]}}}$

**Questions:**

1. How is the average value of $A$ defined?
2. What is the average value of $A$?

It seems extremely obvious that the answer *should* be $1/2$. Realistically, a large enough uniform random sampling of a sufficiently large interval $[a,b]$ will almost always land you with a value of $1/2$; but I don't know how to show that the *average* average is actually $1/2$, and that the apparent tendency towards this value isn't a miraculous coincidence.

Intuitively, I'd think that we'd want to take some kind limit-integral like

$$\overline A=\lim_{R\to[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}}\mu(R)^{-1}\int_R A(T)\ dT$$

Given $|[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}|=|\Bbb R|$ (obviously true), there must be *some* bijection $C:\Bbb R\to[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}$. Assuming that we can define $C$ in a nice way, we could reasonably assert

$$\lim_{R\to[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}}\mu(R)^{-1}\int_R A(T)\ dT=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b A(C(t))\ dt$$

but 1) this requires $A\circ C:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ to be continuous, which I'm not sure is even possible (and I don't know how to prove it either way), 2) there may not be a nice way to define $C$ even *if* such a continuous function does exist.

Comment: (+1) just for the intro

Answer (score 1):

In order for this question to make sense, you need to give a distribution over the sets $T \in [\mathbb R]^{< \mathbb N}$. One way to do this would be to pick a distribution $p$ over $\mathbb N$, a distribution $\mu$ over $\mathbb R$, and propose that we first generate $N \sim p$, then each of the $N$ elements of $T$ independently from $\mu$.

The average value of $A$ will then depend on your choice of $p$ and $\mu$, and will not in general equal $\tfrac12.$ For example, if $\mu \sim U[0, \pi/\omega],$ the average will be 1. I'm assuming you're interested in the case where $\mu$ approximates a uniform distribution on all of $\mathbb R$; no such distribution exists, but we can take a limit, e.g. letting $\mu \sim U[-R, R]$ for $R \to \infty$.

In this case, we obtain

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[A] &= \sum_n p_n\  \mathbb E[A \mid N = n]\\
&= \sum_n p_n \int L\ d\mu\\
&= \frac{1}{2R}\int_{-R}^R \lfloor \sin(\omega t) + 1 \rfloor\ dt,
\end{align*}$$

which equals $\tfrac12$ for any $R$, by symmetry. You can expect similar results for other limits, but the details will depend on what you want to assume about $p$ and $\mu$.

Comment: This is getting at the heart of the problem. We can't rightly assume a distribution over $[\Bbb R]^{<\Bbb N}$ because that would require more information than we have (e.g. the rat's path or the number of times information about the button reaches the rat.) The real challenge is to make sense of the problem *without* making assumptions about the distribution over the set of possible measurements. This is why I assumed a "uniform" distribution, but I don't know enough about probability to say if this is reasonable.